# URL Masking with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, masking

I have a url below:

http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price=

1. if PropertyBuyRent=rent and all other variables are empty then url should be like:
   http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php/TimeshareForRent/All

how can i write htaccess for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(testing/mypage\.php)\?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/TimeshareForRent/All? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(testing/mypage.php)/TimeshareForRent/All/?$ /$1?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price= [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: its not working when im opening my site, like  http://abc.com/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price=

Comment: So you are entering URL as `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price=`?

Comment: yes it should change to that url and open mypage.php/TimeshareForRent/All/   but on back its passing the variables, actually masking  the variables with mypage.php/TimeshareForRent/All/

Comment: oh its not giving error anymore but when i open this link: http://site.com/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price= ... it doesnt change to the other url

Comment: no its inside a folder called testing, can u do something that it works inside a folder?

Comment: No you cannot just place it in any folder. That's not the way .htaccess works. It has to be placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: i mean i can place it in root folder but i want all the above conditions to apply in a folder say its  testing/mypage.php

Comment: If you want it to apply for `testing/mypage.php` then let me edit my answer. But still you need this code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line and make edits in php file as follows

```
RewriteRule ^mypage.php/TimeshareForRent/All/?$ mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=rent&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=&Price= [L,NC,QSA]
```

You can tell your php file to redirect to "mypage.php/TimeshareForRent/All" when your condition matched, because with above rule, it will mask the url of variables with the one without variable